# stringWitFormat using a zero padded float

Tags: ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

```
double knots = currentLocation.speed*1.943844492;
NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03.1f", knots];
```

This results a normal single decimal float without leading zero's.
The purpose is to get max 3 leading digits and single decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `3` is the total length including the decimal point and the decimal digit. Change the `3` to `5` and you should get what you want:

```
NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05.1f", knots];
```

Comment: Thank you rmaddy! A lot slimmer than using NSNumberFormatter!

Comment: You should use `NSNumberFormatter` so the value looks appropriate to a user based on their locale.